# Get the name of namespace xmlns from xsd file through XmlSlurper/XmlParser

Tags: groovy, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to fetch the namespace for an xml(xsd) file through Groovy. 
The Node returned by the XmlParsers, and the GPathResult by XmlSlurper seems to ignore the namespace definitions.

As an example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

trying to fetch the attributes of the rootNode through

```
rootNode.attributes()
```

will retrieve only:

```
targetNamespace:http://www.w3schools.com
elementFormDefault:qualified
```

and leave out the *xml:ns* and *xmlns* definitions. Same result is contained in the @ attribute of GPathResult.

Seems this has nothing to do with the Node class implementation and relies on the XmlParsers used.

So how should the XmlParser be implemented to include these attributes in the node, and any reason this has been left outside of Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different variant of [`XmlSlurper` constructor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper(boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean)):

```
def xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
</xs:schema>
"""

assert new XmlSlurper(false, false, false).parseText(xml).attributes() == [
    'xmlns:xs':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 
    'targetNamespace':'http://www.w3schools.com', 
    'xmlns':'http://www.w3schools.com', 
    'elementFormDefault':'qualified'
]
```

Comment: oh, I did not check the constructors. Thank you.